# how to calculate the size of an image using height width and type android

Tags: android

If we know the `height`, `width`, and `MIME type` of an image or `bitmap`, how can we calculate its size?

As of now, the `bitmap` is not allocated. I am using `inJustDecodeBounds` to get the `height`, `width` and `Mime type`.

Is there some specific method in Android or do we do it using some mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getBitmapByteSize(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        return bitmap.getAllocationByteCount();
    } 
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
        return bitmap.getByteCount();
    }
    else {
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

To get bitmap from ImageView call `((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap()`.

Comment: Thanks, i had seen the code earlier. But as of now, the bitmap is not allocated. I am using inJustDecodeBounds to get the height, width and Mime type.. So I can not use the above methods.

Comment: If you still didn't solve your problem I think I found solution for you. The size of an image will be product of its width, height and bytes per pixel. You already have width and height, so the last thing to do is convert mime type to bytes per pixel. Look at this code [ImageInfo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/GetfileformatimageresolutionnumberofbitsperpixelJPEGGIFBMPPCXPNGIFFRASPBMPGMPPMPSDandSWFfiles.htm) Using `getBitsPerPixel()` method of `ImageInfo` you can check the lacking information and compute the product which will give you the size of image.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is really helpful. But I actually implemented a try catch block to get things done the way I wanted.